# Add a new record to database using a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form (formSale) that is based on a query and contain fields from multiple tables(all the tables are related ) .I want to add a new record to the tables , what code do i need to do that ?

The following command doesn't work

`DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Access has a setting in the Query Properties window called Recordset Type. You need to set this to `Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)` to allow your query to be updatable.

[image]

Source : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20323/unable-to-add-records-to-query-in-access-2007